# Replace within text?

Tags: replace, dependency-injection, angular

Is there any way in Angular 2 to analyse a text and replace certain parts and load stuff from a specified component?

For instance, I have this text:

```
Hello, my name is <myName [usr]="user123"> and I look like in this <myPicture [usr]="user123"> picture.
```

What I'd like to do, is replace the two *variables* with the template of some component, basically injecting the appropriate component into these variables.

Is that possible in Angular 2?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what you want to do. Ideally add more code that demonstrates what you want to accomplish. What do you mean by "template of some component". How do you expect this to behave. Please explain with a concrete example what end-result you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject html in any dom element with directive innerHtml

```
<myName [innerHtml]="myHtmlString">
```